# How to get PHP syntax coloring into html file with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have to use .html files(because of a CMS), but I use some PHP inside. I would like that code between php tags be colored.
My IDE is Eclipse(don't want to change for now).

Any idea ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use PDT (PHP Development Tools) Plugin.
http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/#download